# Passing data to Bootstrap 4 Modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I'm using a PHP script to read data from a database and create an image gallery based on the results using Bootstrap Cards. Now I would like to have the possibility to delete data from the gallery. I finally found a way to do this -

**PHP code:**

```
[...]
echo "<div class='col-sm-4'>";
echo "<div class='card-deck'>";
echo "<div class='card' id='id_".$uploads[$i]['id']."'>";
echo "<img class='card-img-top' src='".$imagePath.$uploads[$i]['md5']."_tn.jpg' alt='Card image cap'>";
echo "<div class='card-img-overlay'><a class='close' href='#'>×</a></div>";
echo "<div class='card-body'>";
[...]
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.close').click(function(){
        var target = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
        $.ajax({url:'delete.php?id=' + target.replace('id_', '')});
        location.reload();
    });
});
```

This works perfectly fine, but I would like to include a Bootstrap Modal before actually deleting the picture from the gallery.

**HTML modal code:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Delete picture</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">Do you really want to delete this picture?</div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" id="deletePic" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Picture</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**PHP code:**

```
[...]
echo "<div class='col-sm-4'>";
echo "<div class='card-deck'>";
echo "<div class='card' id='id_".$uploads[$i]['id']."'>";
echo "<img class='card-img-top' src='".$imagePath.$uploads[$i]['md5']."_tn.jpg' alt='Card image cap'>";
echo "<div class='card-img-overlay'><a class='close' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#deleteModal' href='#'>×</a></div>";
echo "<div class='card-body'>";
[...]
```

Since the modal is now an additional step between the click on the X button and the actual delete my Javascript will not work anymore. Could someone please let me know how I can hand over the picture ID to the modal and in the next step delete the picture?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for better response.

Comment: the bootbox library is useful for stuff like this. It allows  you to easily run dialog boxes with callback functions and all that good stuff http://bootboxjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can do this:

```
$('a.close').click(function(){
    var target = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
    var pictureId = target.replace('id_', '');

    $("#deletePic").data('picture-id', pictureId);

    $("#deleteModal").modal("show");
});
```

Above code, we changed something. Firstly we removed ajax request. After that, we assigned picture id to delete button in the modal. After that, we opened the `#deleteModal`

Now, we know `#deletePic` has picture's ID number.

If we want to delete picture when clicked `#deletePic` button, we should use this:

```
$("#deletePic").on("click", function() {
    var pictureId = $(this).data('picture-id');

    $.ajax({url:'delete.php?id=' + pictureId});
});
```

And you shouldn't miss that, there are two `.close` class.

Firstly anchor has `.close` class that you want to use it. Also, bootstrap's modal contains `.close` class. So you should work `ELEMENT.CLASSNAME` if there are different elements has the same class.

I hope this will work for you.